# Socket IO event firing multiple times NodeJS

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am building a quiz application in NodeJS and Android using socket.IO,

I am facing a problem when I emit an event `quizzoStatus` from the server, the event fires first time once, second time twice and so on.

Here I attach my code snippet

```
///server side: NodeJS
socket.on('sendQuizzoAnsPoints', async (data)=>{
          try {
              const obj = JSON.parse(data);
              const game = await QuizzoPlayModel.findOne({_id:obj.gameId});
              const player = await UserModel.findOne({_id: game.playerId});
              const opponent = await UserModel.findOne({_id: game.opponentId});
              if(obj.userId == game.opponentId){
                  let update = {
                      opponentPoints: game.opponentPoints + obj.points || 0,
                      opponentWA: game.opponentWA + obj.wrongAns || 0,
                  };
                  await QuizzoPlayModel.findByIdAndUpdate(obj.gameId, update).lean().exec();
                  userNamespace.to(player.socketId).emit('quizzoStatus', {
                      fullName: opponent.fullName,
                      points: game.playerPoints + obj.points,
                      wrongAns: obj.wrongAns,
                      gameId: obj.gameId
                  });
              }
              if(obj.userId == game.playerId) {
                  let update = {
                      playerPoints: game.playerPoints + obj.points || 0,
                      playerWA: game.playerWA + obj.wrongAns || 0,
                  };
                  await QuizzoPlayModel.findByIdAndUpdate(obj.gameId, update).lean().exec();
                  userNamespace.to(opponent.socketId).emit('quizzoStatus', {
                      fullName: player.fullName,
                      points: game.playerPoints+ obj.points,
                      wrongAns: obj.wrongAns,
                      gameId: obj.gameId
                  });
              }
          } catch (e) {
              console.log(e);
          }
        });
```

Here I listen a event named `sendQuizzoAnsPoints` and then I emit an event to the player or opponent in another event named `quizzoStatus`.

> The `quizzoStatus` event fires multiple times from server to android.
>   Here I attached android code

```
/// Android code
socket.emit("sendQuizzoAnsPoints", new Gson().toJson(quizzoStatusRequestDto)); 
socket.on("quizzoStatus", new Emitter.Listener(){
           @Override
           public void call(Object... args){
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                   @Override
                   public void run(){
                       Log.e("opponet point", opponentPoints + " " + quizzoStatusResponseDto.getPoints());
                   }
               });
           }
       });
```

Comment: Seems your client(android) connecting multiple time to the server

Comment: I check it already, the client connected once, but at the same time, there are two or more clients connected from different devices.

Comment: Every device connect with the same ID ?

Comment: No, each device connected with a different ID. @ŞivāSankĂr

Comment: Log all your connected device(ID) after server restart. Just put `console.log()` before `socket.join()`

Comment: I have already checked it, every device connected with a unique ID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188247/discussion-between-md-alamin-and-siv-sankr).

Comment: Try to using [Socket.io tester](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm?hl=en) and test your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in `Android`. You are assigning new listener every time without removing the previous one. You need to create a variable of that `Emmiter` listener and remove it on `onDestroy` or somewhere else when the work is done:

```
    //variable of Emmiter.Listener
    Emmiter.Listener quizzoStatus = new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override public void call(Object... args){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override public void run(){
                    Log.e("opponet point", opponentPoints + " " + quizzoStatusResponseDto.getPoints());
                }
            });
        }
    };

    //assigning the listener
    socket.on("quizzoStatus", quizzoStatus);
    . . . .
    @Override protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        //removing the listener...
        socket.off("quizzoStatus", quizzoStatus);
    }
```

Hope this will work

Comment: This is also useful when coming back from onActivityResult after uploading a photo/media... the earlier listener is attached and a new one gets attached... for me it works in onStop